# What is the equivalent of "Field at Index"? (Blender 3.5)

Tags: geometry-nodes

What resources are there that show the differences in nodes between versions?

I'm following this tutorial and can't find the "Field at Index" node:
[12:00](https://youtu.be/NtVR76OPh9s?t=720) (Bricks Tutorial)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the ["Evaluate at Index"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field/evaluate_at_index.html) node now. Ignore the photo. It hasn't been updated on the wiki.